# How to get each individual replacement result from a Regex replacement?

Tags: java, regex, replace

#### question

How to get **each individual replacement result** from a Regex replacement?

#### ex

`String regexMatchedWord = matcher.group();` allows me to access the current matched result;

But is there something like `String regexMatchedSubstitution = matcher.currentMatchedReplacementResult();` allows me to access **the current replacement result**?

```java
public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String content_SearchOn = "Sample sentence: snake, snail, snow, spider";
    String regexStrSubstitution = "$2$3$1";
    String regexStrMatchFor = "(s)(.)(.)";

    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regexStrMatchFor).matcher(content_SearchOn);

    ArrayList<String> arr_regexMatchedWord = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> arr_regexMatchedSubstitution = new ArrayList<>();

    StringBuilder sb_content_Replaced = new StringBuilder();
    while (matcher.find()) {
      String regexMatchedWord = matcher.group();
      arr_regexMatchedWord.add(regexMatchedWord);

      matcher.appendReplacement(sb_content_Replaced, regexStrSubstitution);

      String regexMatchedSubstitution = null; // << What should I put here -- to get each replacement result?
      arr_regexMatchedSubstitution.add(regexMatchedSubstitution);
    }
    matcher.appendTail(sb_content_Replaced);

    System.out.println(sb_content_Replaced); // Sample enstence: naske, nasil, nosw, pisder
    System.out.println(arr_regexMatchedWord); // [sen, sna, sna, sno, spi]
    System.out.println(arr_regexMatchedSubstitution); // [ens, nas, nas, nos, pis] // << expect

  }

}
```

#### comments

- if Java is not able to do this, is there any other language able to? (Javascript? Python?)

---

***Update***: potential solution (workaround)

- (as talked in the comment) A simple possible way might be:

  convert those `$1` into `group(1)` programmatically,

  but you have to watch out for the escape characters like `\` that has special meaning...
- Another way might be:

  use Reflection to somehow get the local variable `result` in the source code `appendExpandedReplacement(replacement, result);` of `java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(StringBuilder, String)`

  ```java
    public Matcher appendReplacement(StringBuilder sb, String replacement) {
        // If no match, return error
        if (first < 0)
            throw new IllegalStateException("No match available");
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        appendExpandedReplacement(replacement, result);
        // Append the intervening text
        sb.append(text, lastAppendPosition, first);
        // Append the match substitution
        sb.append(result);
        lastAppendPosition = last;
        modCount++;
        return this;
    }
  ```
- Or:

  Record the end index before the append & count from that index to get the Appended Replacement after the append.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? It seems like you just want `matcher.group(2) + matcher.group(3) + matcher.group(1)`?

Comment: @Sweeper true... maybe the example is not general enough... let me edit it.

Comment: @Sweeper ## Actually, you are right 
- (I couldnt come up with other example -- cuz Java replacemnt syntax is actual simpler than I thought... eg: there is no things like `\U \E`) 
- (I should have thought of your simple solution...). 
## *But 2 more questions*: 
- so, to get the replacement, all I need to do is just: convert those literal `$1` into `group(1)` & leave other text as they are, right? -- is there no simpler way to do it?
- if I am not given the regex replacement string -- I wont know the groups, then can I still get the replacement result?

Comment: I don't know about you, but I personally think the replacement string syntax is relatively complicated, considering there are escape characters and things. You can see how they parse it in [the source of `appendReplacement`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/regex/Matcher.java#l794).

Comment: @Sweeper - That seems like I cant just simply convert those `$1` into `group(1)` (source code process them one character by one character)... 
- Thats also what I afraid & why I was asking for a *standardized function like* `matcher.currentMatchedReplacementResult();` (if such exist) ...

Comment: Please add some examples of input and expected output to your question. Or is it as simple as `Sample sentence: snake, snail, snow, spider` should produce `Sample enstence: naske, nasil, nosw, pisder`?

Answer (score 1):

#### solution (workaround) Java implementation

- @logic::

  > Record the end index before the append & count from that index to get the Appended Replacement after the append.
- @code::

  ```java
    public class Test {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        String content_SearchOn = "Sample sentence: snake, snail, snow, spider";
        String regexStrSubstitution = "$2$3x$1";
        String regexStrMatchFor = "(s)(.)(.).";

        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regexStrMatchFor).matcher(content_SearchOn);

        ArrayList<String> arr_regexMatchedWord = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> arr_regexMatchedSubstitution = new ArrayList<>();

        StringBuilder sb_content_SearchOn = new StringBuilder(content_SearchOn);
        StringBuilder sb_content_Replaced = new StringBuilder();

        String content_OriPlusCurrAppendSubsti = null;
        StringBuilder sb_CurrAppendSubsti_buffer = null;

        int indStart_g0_curr = -1;
        int indEnd_g0_curr = -1;
        int indStart_g0_prev = -1;
        int indEnd_g0_prev = -1;
        while (matcher.find()) {
          // #>>>#
          String regexMatchedWord = matcher.group();
          indStart_g0_curr = matcher.start();
          indEnd_g0_curr = matcher.end();
          arr_regexMatchedWord.add(regexMatchedWord);

          // #>>>
          // @main[business logic]::

          // <strike> length_sb_content_Replaced_prev = sb_content_Replaced.length();
          // <strike> String regexMatchedSubstitution = sb_content_Replaced.substring(length_sb_content_Replaced_prev);
          // @note: it appends both the `the intervening text` + `the match substitution` ...

          //need_check,need_confrim_recall if multi call? // matcher.appendReplacement(new StringBuilder(), regexStrSubstitution); // ok its broken, so cant

          //~ matcher.appendReplacement(sb_content_Replaced, regexStrSubstitution);
          sb_CurrAppendSubsti_buffer = new StringBuilder();
          matcher.appendReplacement(sb_CurrAppendSubsti_buffer, regexStrSubstitution + "_$0");
          sb_content_Replaced.append(sb_CurrAppendSubsti_buffer);
          // @main;;

          // #>>>
          // @main[get the individual replacement result]::
          //~ String regexMatchedSubstitution = null; // << What should I put here -- to get each replacement result?
          if (indEnd_g0_prev == -1) {
            content_OriPlusCurrAppendSubsti = "";
          } else {
            content_OriPlusCurrAppendSubsti = sb_content_SearchOn.substring(0, indEnd_g0_prev);
          }
          content_OriPlusCurrAppendSubsti += sb_CurrAppendSubsti_buffer;
          String regexMatchedSubstitution = content_OriPlusCurrAppendSubsti.substring(indStart_g0_curr);
          arr_regexMatchedSubstitution.add(regexMatchedSubstitution);
          // @main;;

          // #>>>#
          indStart_g0_prev = indStart_g0_curr;
          indEnd_g0_prev = indEnd_g0_curr;
        }
        matcher.appendTail(sb_content_Replaced);

        //
        System.out.println(sb_content_Replaced); // Sample enxs_sentence: naxs_snake, naxs_snail, noxs_snow, pixs_spider
        System.out.println(arr_regexMatchedWord); // [sent, snak, snai, snow, spid]
        System.out.println(arr_regexMatchedSubstitution); // [enxs_sent, naxs_snak, naxs_snai, noxs_snow, pixs_spid] // << expect

      }

    }
  ```

#### solution (workaround) Javascript implementation

- @logic::

  simply brute force with `hardcode string delimiter indicator` in regex

  1. `replaceAll()` -- add brackets around the `matched replacement` during replacement
  2. `matchAll()` -- search the `matched replacement` that was enclosed in the brackets
- @code (moved from specific example to a general class [here])::

  ```js
    class RegexUtil {
      // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript
      // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex
      /**
       * @param {String} literal_string
       * @returns {String}
       */
      static escapeRegex(literal_string) {
        return literal_string.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+!<=:?.\/\\^$|#\s,]/g, '\\$&');
      }

      /**
       * @param {String} string
       * @returns {String}
       */
      static escapeRegexReplacement(string) {
        return string.replace(/\$/g, '$$$$');
      }

      /**
       * @param {String} content_SearchOn 
       * @param {RegExp} regexMatchFor 
       * @param {String} regexStrSubstitution 
       * @param {String} regexFlag 
       * @returns {String[]}
       */
      static get_RegexMatchedReplacement(content_SearchOn, regexMatchFor, regexStrSubstitution) {
        const arr_regexMatchedSubstitution = [];

        let time_now;
        let delim_regexMatchedSub_left;
        let delim_regexMatchedSub_right;
        /** @type {IterableIterator<RegExpMatchArray>} */ let itr;
        let i = 0;
        do {
          i++;
          if (i === 50) {
            throw new Error('Many loops tried, Unable to brute force with hardcode string indicator in regex. (The chance of this happening is nearly impossible.)');
          }
          time_now = Date.now();
          delim_regexMatchedSub_left = '@drmsL' + time_now + ';';
          delim_regexMatchedSub_right = '@drmsR' + time_now + ';';
          itr = content_SearchOn.matchAll(new RegExp(RegexUtil.escapeRegex(delim_regexMatchedSub_left) + '|' + RegexUtil.escapeRegex(delim_regexMatchedSub_right), 'g'));
        } while (itr.next().done !== true);

        const content_Replaced_WithDelimiter = content_SearchOn.replaceAll(regexMatchFor, RegexUtil.escapeRegexReplacement(delim_regexMatchedSub_left) + regexStrSubstitution + RegexUtil.escapeRegexReplacement(delim_regexMatchedSub_right));
        itr = content_Replaced_WithDelimiter.matchAll(new RegExp(RegexUtil.escapeRegex(delim_regexMatchedSub_left) + '(.*?)' + RegexUtil.escapeRegex(delim_regexMatchedSub_right), 'gs')); // need flag s
        for (const matcher_curr of itr) {
          arr_regexMatchedSubstitution.push(matcher_curr[1]);
        }

        return arr_regexMatchedSubstitution;
      }
    }
  ```
- @code (moved from specific example [here] to a general class)::

  ```js
      class RegexUtil {
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex
        /**
         * @param {String} literal_string
         * @returns {String}
         */
        static escapeRegex(literal_string) {
          return literal_string.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+!<=:?.\/\\^$|#\s,]/g, '\\$&');
        }

        /**
         * @param {String} string
         * @returns {String}
         */
        static escapeRegexReplacement(string) {
          return string.replace(/\$/g, '$$$$');
        }
      }

      //think aga, to use a generic way to escape special meaning delimiter in regex ...
      const content_SearchOn = 'Sample sentence: snake, snail, snow, spider';
      let regexStrSubstitution = '$2$3x$1';
      const regexStrMatchFor = '(s)(.)(.).';
      const regexFlag = 'gmd';

      regexStrSubstitution += '_$&';

      const arr_regexMatchedWord = [];
      const arr_regexMatchedSubstitution = [];

      let time_now;
      let delim_regexMatchedSub_left;
      let delim_regexMatchedSub_right;
      /** @type {IterableIterator<RegExpMatchArray>} */ let itr;
      let i = 0;
      do {
        i++;
        if (i === 50) {
          throw new Error('Many loops tried, Unable to brute force with hardcode string indicator in regex. (The chance of this happening is nearly impossible.)');
        }
        time_now = Date.now();
        delim_regexMatchedSub_left = '@drmsL' + time_now + ';';
        delim_regexMatchedSub_right = '@drmsR' + time_now + ';';
        itr = content_SearchOn.matchAll(new RegExp(RegexUtil.escapeRegex(delim_regexMatchedSub_left) + '|' + RegexUtil.escapeRegex(delim_regexMatchedSub_right), 'g'));
      } while (itr.next().done !== true);

      const content_Replaced_WithDelimiter = content_SearchOn.replaceAll(new RegExp(regexStrMatchFor, regexFlag), RegexUtil.escapeRegexReplacement(delim_regexMatchedSub_left) + regexStrSubstitution + RegexUtil.escapeRegexReplacement(delim_regexMatchedSub_right));
      itr = content_Replaced_WithDelimiter.matchAll(new RegExp(RegexUtil.escapeRegex(delim_regexMatchedSub_left) + '(.*?)' + RegexUtil.escapeRegex(delim_regexMatchedSub_right), 'gs')); // need flag s
      for (const matcher_curr of itr) {
        arr_regexMatchedSubstitution.push(matcher_curr[1]);
      }

      itr = content_SearchOn.matchAll(new RegExp(regexStrMatchFor, regexFlag));
      for (const matcher_curr of itr) {
        arr_regexMatchedWord.push(matcher_curr[0]);
      }

      const content_Replaced = content_SearchOn.replaceAll(new RegExp(regexStrMatchFor, regexFlag), regexStrSubstitution);

      console.log(content_Replaced); // Sample enxs_sentence: naxs_snake, naxs_snail, noxs_snow, pixs_spider
      console.log(arr_regexMatchedWord); // [sent, snak, snai, snow, spid]
      console.log(arr_regexMatchedSubstitution); // [enxs_sent, naxs_snak, naxs_snai, noxs_snow, pixs_spid] // << expect
  ```

##### comment (minor)

- The reason to brute force it with `hardcode string indicator in regex` is that,

  Javascript is even worse at:

  - not providing the `appendReplacement()`
  - `replacer callback function` does not support those `$1`

    > **Note:** The above-mentioned special replacement patterns do *not* apply for strings returned from the replacer function.
    >
    > https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_the_replacement
- > replacer callback function does not support those `$1`

  Which makes this following idea useless (could have work) (complex & low performance) ::

  ```js
      for (const matcher_curr of itr_matcher) {
        ind_ReplaceOnlyCurrOne++;

        let ind_Match = -1;
        function replace_OnlyOneWord_c_for_get_regexMatchedSubstitution(...args) {
          ind_Match++;
          /** @type {String} */ const g0 = args[0]; 
          if (ind_Match === ind_ReplaceOnlyCurrOne) {
            // prettier-ignore 
            let arg_last = args.at(-1); let ind_g0; let content_SearchOn; let groups;
            // prettier-ignore 
            if (typeof arg_last === 'string') { content_SearchOn = arg_last; ind_g0 = args.at(-2); } else { groups = arg_last; content_SearchOn = args.at(-2); ind_g0 = args.at(-3); }

            arr_regexMatchedWord.push(g0);
            indStart_g0 = ind_g0;
            indEnd_g0 = ind_g0 + g0.length;

            return replacer_main(args);
          } else {
            return RegexUtil.escapeRegexReplacement(g0);
          }
        }

        const content_ReplacedOnlyCurrOne__P1_Pm_P2 = content_SearchOn.replaceAll(new RegExp(regexStrMatchFor, regexFlag), replace_OnlyOneWord_c_for_get_regexMatchedSubstitution);
        const Pm_P2 = content_ReplacedOnlyCurrOne__P1_Pm_P2.slice(indStart_g0);
        const P2 = content_SearchOn.slice(indEnd_g0);
        const regexMatchedSubstitution__Pm = Pm_P2.replaceAll(new RegExp(RegexUtil.escapeRegexp(P2)+'$', 'g'), '');
        arr_regexMatchedSubstitution.push(regexMatchedSubstitution__Pm);
      }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`replaceAll(Function<MatchResult, String> replacer)`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/panama/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.util.function.Function)) on a `Matcher` to "intercept" the replacement:

```java
String input = "Sample sentence: snake, snail, snow, spider";
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
String result = Pattern.compile("(s)(.)(.)").matcher(input)
  .replaceAll(mr -> {
     matches.add(mr.group());
     return mr.group(2) + mr.group(3) + mr.group(1);
  });
System.out.println(result);
System.out.println(matches);
```

Output:

```
Sample enstence: naske, nasil, nosw, pisder
[sen, sna, sna, sno, spi]
```

Comment: - Close but not really what I look for, this was discussed in the comments. - Also this only solves this particular ex, I was looking for a more *general* solution. - My question_post wrote the *potential way* to do it. - And I just *uploaded code* for one of the possible way in my answer_post, (though its long & codes arent structuralized prettily).

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Is it that you want to get a list of all the original matches? Eg `[sen, sna, sna, sno, spi]`?

Comment: In the ex code of my question_post: - `String regexMatchedSubstitution = null; // << What should I put here -- to get each replacement result?` -- this is what I ultimately want for all general cases. - `System.out.println(arr_regexMatchedSubstitution); // [ens, nas, nas, nos, pis] // << expect` -- this is the expected result only for this particular example. - (The ex I use in my answer_post varied a bit, but the general idea&purpose didnt change.)

Comment: @Nor.Z see edits to my answer that capture the matched parts of the original string. I don't think I can do much better than this.

Comment: You misunderstood my post. I know can get `the current matched result`, but I want `the current replacement result`, and solution should be more general (not limited only to the ex I provided). (but dont worry, I have a workaround)